# Selenium WebDriverでHTTP refererを設定する方法をご教授下さい。

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium WebDriverでHTTP refererを設定する方法をご教授下さい。
chromeを使用しています。

■やりたい事
http://referer.com/ → http://target.com/

■実装イメージ

```
options->AddArgument("--referer=http://referer.com/");
driver->Navigate()->GoToUrl("http://target.com/");
```

■環境
Win7 64bit
visual studio
Chrome driver

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/10321

Comment: マルチポスト　https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9862343.html

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14177374024

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/86376

Comment: マルチポスト　https://medaka.2ch.net/test/read.cgi/php/1501464709/